# Google Nearby Connection Api - Unfortunately Play Service Stopped

Tags: android, android-studio, google-play-services, google-nearby

I am working on an android project using Google Nearby Connection api. All is going fine. I can connect multiple device properly.

The only problem is if `mGoogleApiClient.disconnect();` called in any case `"Unfortunately google play service stopped"` this alert appeared.

I also tried `Nearby.Connections.disconnectFromEndpoint(mGoogleApiClient, remoteEndpointId);` or `Nearby.Connections.stopAllEndpoints(mGoogleApiClient);` for disconnecting.But same thing occurred.

Even when `stop discovery` or `stop advertising` methods called this alert appeared. This is not a crash and I did not find any error on Log.

I initialize api client and set the override methods as documentation. `Start advertising` and `start discovery` methods are also taken from documentation.

In my gradle I used `compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-nearby:10.0.1'`.

Then, what may be the problem. Please, help me and Thanks in advance.

Comment: From this [documentation](https://developers.google.com/nearby/connections/android/get-started), You can disconnect the client once your game no longer needs access to this service. Connect the GoogleApiClient in your activity’s onStart() and disconnect it in onStop(). Try also to check the disconnection part of this [tutorial](https://code.tutsplus.com/tutorials/google-play-services-using-the-nearby-connections-api--cms-24534).

Comment: Hi @bhoot4242, did you find a solution? For me it only happens when I call `Nearby.Connections.stopDiscovery(mGoogleApiClient, service_id);`

Answer (score 0):

put this condition wherever you want to disconnect:

```
if (mGoogleApiClient != null && mGoogleApiClient.isConnected()) {
            mGoogleApiClient.disconnect();}
```